# Probability of drawing balls without replacement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I saw this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641383/probability-of-a-game-of-drawing-balls/), but since it's on hold I have no other choice than reposting it.

Suppose there are $2$ players, $r≥1$ red balls and $(n−r)$ black balls in the bin, what is the probability that first player draw the red ball first?

I've already solved the case where the balls are drawn with replacement, this one however seems more complex.

Here's my attempt:

Let A be the case that the first player draws the red ball, and B be the case that the second one draws the red ball.

$P(A)=A+A'B'A+A'B'A'B'A+\dots$

$P(A)=\frac{r}{n}+(\frac{n-r}{n}\cdot\frac{n-r-1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{r}{n-2})+(\frac{n-r}{n}\cdot\frac{n-r-1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-r-2}{n-2}\cdot\frac{n-r-3}{n-3}\cdot\frac{r}{n-4})+\dots+(\frac{n-r}{n}\cdot\frac{n-r-1}{n-1}\cdots\frac{2}{r+2}\cdot\frac{1}{r+1}\cdot\frac{r}{r})$

Nevertheless I have no idea how we can evalute this sum.

Comment: your calculatiob seem to be without replacement? i dont understanf what you are asking?

Comment: Can we express it compactly though? It doesn't seem easy to compute given that n is big.

Comment: Do we know if $n$ and/or $r$ are even?

Comment: No, we're not given that information.

Comment: @Zafer Cesur something seems wrong in that summation. It starts with $(\frac{n-r}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-r-1}{n-2}\cdot\frac{r}{n-3})$, I think it should be $(\frac{n-r}{n}\cdot\frac{n-r-1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{r}{n-2})$ and so on...

Comment: Yes that is a brain malfunction right there!

Answer (score 1):

I used another method to approach:

Number of all ways to draw all balls is $n \choose r$. Now we consider the following cases:

**Case 1:** First player draw the first red ball in his/her first attempt. Number of ways is $n-1 \choose r-1$;

**Case 2:** First player draw the first red ball in his/her second attempt. Number of ways is $n-3 \choose r-1$;

**Case 3:** First player draw the first red ball in his/her third attempt. Number of ways is $n-5 \choose r-1$;

$\vdots$

so the desired probability should be
$$\frac{{n-1 \choose r-1}+{n-3 \choose r-1}+{n-5 \choose r-1}+\cdots}{n \choose r}$$

and I have no idea about the value of numerator!

Comment: But don't these cases assume that the game continues till the very end, although the red ball has already been drawn?

Comment: These are all possible winning cases. unless we end it whenever the first red ball drawn, still I'm not sure how this affect the result.

Comment: Yes, correct. I'm trying to evaluate this sum, yours is significantly better than mine.

Comment: Maybe a hockeystick identity would work?

Comment: I tried that too. But I I don't no how to deal with missed parts.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I've proven that the nominator equals $n\choose r-1$

Comment: I think $n=5$ and $r=2$ is a counterexample!

Comment: I think for $r > 2$ it is true, let me post it as an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12557/discussion-between-woso-and-zafer-cesur)

Comment: Yeah it was false. I surrender!